# What is the name of this optimization problem?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

suppose that we can describe a problem with two formulas, i.e. we have:

> f(a,b) and  g(b,c) with unknown a,b,c

with

> a=inv(c)

and we have such optimization algorithm as a solution:

> -1: start with random a, name it old-a
> -2: solve f(old-a,b), and find b
> -3: put b in g(b,c), and find c
> -4: now we have an approximation of a: new-a = inv(c)
> -5: old-a = new-a, go to step 1, until we reached to an err such that err=(new-a - old-a)<epsilon

What is the name of this optimization?

I know it could be a multi-objective optimization, goal programming, a kind of linear programming, or some chain ... but I want a certain name of optimization problem or sub-class name, with an exact definition of it. I mean, if it is a sub-class of LP, then what is the sub-class name, and where is a reference book or paper?

Comment: Maybe you are describing a form of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)?

Comment: @Neil, my question is about an evolutionary optimization problem, which newton-raphson method is a kind of that.

Comment: Is `b` just a temporary variable to link `f` and `g`?

Comment: b is an essential part of their formulation. f is a z-transform of a systems transfer function in frequency-domain, and g is another transformation in time-domain. @Neil

Comment: That really helps understand the context. Unfortunately, I have no answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question from several students, and they said that it is not a special algorithm, it is just a kind of ***evolutionary optimization***.